# PHP Registration Form not adding data to database (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a PHP Registration form and connected it with the database. However when i register using the form, the data is not added to the database. (I am using Hostinger as my hosting server). What is the issue here? i am fairly new to PHP.

Below are the codes for your reference.

1. Register.php

```
<?php  include('config.php'); ?>
<!-- Source code for handling registration and login -->
<?php  include('includes/registration_login.php'); ?>

<?php include('includes/head_section.php'); ?>

<title>My Blog| Sign up </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <!-- Navbar -->
                <?php include( ROOT_PATH . '/includes/navbar.php'); ?>
        <!-- // Navbar -->

        <div style="width: 40%; margin: 20px auto;">
                <form method="post" action="register.php" >
                        <h2>Register on Found Bhutan</h2>
                        <?php include(ROOT_PATH . '/includes/errors.php'); ?>
                        <input  type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"  placeholder="Username">
                        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="password" name="password_1" placeholder="Password">
                        <input type="password" name="password_2" placeholder="Password confirmation">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Register</button>
                        <p>
                                Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
                        </p>
                </form>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- // container -->
<!-- Footer -->
        <?php include( ROOT_PATH . '/includes/footer.php'); ?>
<!-- // Footer -->
```

2. Config.php (Database Connection File)

```
<?php

        session_start();
        // connect to database


        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "Secret", "databasename");

        if (!$conn) {
                die("Error connecting to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

  // define global constants
        define ('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
        define('BASE_URL', 'http://website.com/blog/');
?>
```

3. registration_login.php (Function for Registration & login)

```
<?php 
        // variable declaration
        $username = "";
        $email    = "";
        $errors = array(); 

        // REGISTER USER
        if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
                // receive all input values from the form
                $username = esc($_POST['username']);
                $email = esc($_POST['email']);
                $password_1 = esc($_POST['password_1']);
                $password_2 = esc($_POST['password_2']);

                // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
                if (empty($username)) {  array_push($errors, "Uhmm...We gonna need your username"); }
                if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Oops.. Email is missing"); }
                if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "uh-oh you forgot the password"); }
                if ($password_1 != $password_2) { array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");}

                // Ensure that no user is registered twice. 
                // the email and usernames should be unique
                $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' 
                                                                OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
                $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                if ($user) { // if user exists
                        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
                          array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
                        }
                        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
                          array_push($errors, "Email already exists");
                        }
                }
                // register user if there are no errors in the form
                if (count($errors) == 0) {
                        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
                        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, created_at, updated_at) 
                                          VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', now(), now())";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                        // get id of created user
                        $reg_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); 

                        // put logged in user into session array
                        $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($reg_user_id);

                        // if user is admin, redirect to admin area
                        if ( in_array($_SESSION['user']['role'], ["Admin", "Author"])) {
                                $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                                // redirect to admin area
                                header('location: ' . BASE_URL . 'admin/dashboard.php');
                                exit(0);
                        } else {
                                $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                                // redirect to public area
                                header('location: index.php');                          
                                exit(0);
                        }
                }
        }


        // LOG USER IN
        if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) 
        
        {
                $username = esc($_POST['username']);
                $password = esc($_POST['password']);

                if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username required"); }
                if (empty($password)) { array_push($errors, "Password required"); }
                if (empty($errors)) {
                        $password = md5($password); // encrypt password
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1";

                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                // get id of created user
                                $reg_user_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['id']; 

                                // put logged in user into session array
                                $_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($reg_user_id); 

                                // if user is admin, redirect to admin area
                                if ( in_array($_SESSION['user']['role'], ["Admin", "Author"])) {
                                        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                                        // redirect to admin area
                                        header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/dashboard.php');
                                        exit(0);
                                } else {
                                        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                                        // redirect to public area
                                        header('location: index.php');                          
                                        exit(0);
                                }
                        } else {
                                array_push($errors, 'Wrong credentials');
                        }
                }
        }

    // escape value from form
    function esc(String $value)
    {       
            // bring the global db connect object into function
            global $conn;

            $val = trim($value); // remove empty space sorrounding string
            $val = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);

            return $val;
    }
    // Get user info from user id
    function getUserById($id)
    {
            global $conn;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            // returns user in an array format: 
            return $user; 
    }

?>
```

NOTE***

1. I have other php files such as login.php, logout.php, errors.php, index.php coded in the same manner as above.
2. I am using Hostinger.
3. Database connection is created (successful), and also table for storing user details is created in database.
4. After filling up the registration forms, it doesn't give any errors or warnings. The database remains empty without any user data. What am i missing here? Please help

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. mysqli_real_escape_string is obsolete and doesn't guard against everything.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords using the obsolete, insecure md5 algorithm - that is another security risk. Learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). Again, if you got this from a tutorial, it's clearly a bad, out of date one. Sign up for a reputable course, and/or buy a good, modern book on PHP.

Comment: To make your code more robust (unless you're on PHP 8.1 or above where this is already enabled by default), add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. You should, for debugging purposes, also enable PHP's general error reporting. Or for a live server, enable error _logging_ to a file instead. Then check your log file for errors when you run your code.

Comment: `I am using Hostinger`...fine, but you shouldn't be using that for _writing_ your code. Develop your code on your local machine (you can install all the necessary tools by using something like XAMPP, plus a code editor like Visual Studio Code), so you can debug it more easily. Then upload it to your hosting account when it's ready to be used.

Comment: WARNING: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong (many of which are demonstrated in this code, as I've noted). Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. There's no need to re-invent the wheel (badly) - it's really not a good topic for a novice coder.